# How to check if a method is called with a specific object in mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have a test which looks like following:

```
 @Test
    public void testMessKonzepteValues() throws Exception {
        String generateTest = generateTest( "String", "String", "String" );
        verify(mockOnlineClient,times(1)).setRequestObject(capturedObjectRequest.capture());

    }
```

The generateTest method calls the setRequestObject method. I want to verivy with a argumentcaptor from mockito if the Object is called with a specific object but I am getting the following error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
gMOnlineClient.setRequestObject(
    OnlineServiceStub$ObjectRequest@164a62bf
);
-> at integrations_test_architecture.OnlineMassInfostIntegrationsTest2.testKonzepteValues(OnlineMassInfostIntegrationsTest2.java:101)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
gMOnlineClient.setRequestObject(
    OnlineServiceStub$ObjectRequest@11ebb1b6
);
-> at punkt.sendObjectMethod(punkt.java:3063)
```

What does this error say? I just said that it should catch the object after being called nothing more. Can someone explain it to me

Comment: What is `capturedObjectRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

It means the argument passed to the `setRequestObject()` method when it was actually invoked during the test does not match the argument that was expected by the test.

Memory address of the expected and actual objects are different (164a62bf and 11ebb1b6). The difference in memory addresses means that the expected and actual objects are not the same instance, even though they may have the same properties.

Comment: But I want to check the properties for example the values inside they do not have to be the same instance rather its not possible because I do not pass my object generated inside the test. So how can I check the values inside those objects?

Comment: You can use [ArgumentCaptor](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture argument and then check its properties using assertions.